# Sequelize model getters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

What is the correct way of using `this.getDataValue` in a [getter function](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#defining-as-part-of-a-property) for a Sequelize model when using TypeScript?

This is the error I'm getting:

> Property 'getDataValue' does not exist on type 'string | DataTypeAbstract | DefineAttributeColumnOptions'.
>
> Property 'getDataValue' does not exist on type 'string'.

My model definition:

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../db-connection';

export interface IUserAttributes {
    date_of_birth: Date;
    name: string;
}

export interface IUserInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<IUserAttributes> {
    date_of_birth: Date;
    name: string;
}

const User = sequelize.define<IUserAttributes, IUserInstance>('user', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
        },
    },
    date_of_birth: {
        get(): Date {
            return new Date(this.getDataValue('date_of_birth'));
        },
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        validate: {
            isDate: true,
            notEmpty: true,
        },
    },
});

export default User;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the type for `this` inside the getter function

```
const User = sequelize.define<IUserAttributes, IUserInstance>('user', {
  name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
      },
  },
  date_of_birth: {
      get(this: IUserInstance): Date {
          return new Date(this.getDataValue('date_of_birth'));
      },
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      validate: {
          isDate: true,
          notEmpty: true,
      },
  },
});
```

**Note** The `this` argument will not get emitted to JS it is just for the benefit of the typescript compiler.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any documentation on this? (no pun intended) All I can find is discussion on this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3694

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Nope .. that is the extent of the documentation I know of :(

Comment: Any idea how you'd go about setters? I thought of adding the type annotation of this as a second argument but TS wouldn't stand for that.

Answer (score 3):

For `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`, `"typescript": "^3.7.5"` and define the sequelize model using TypeScript class based style.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {
  public date_of_birth!: Date;
  public name!: string;
}
User.init(
  {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
      },
    },
    date_of_birth: {
      get(this: User): Date {
        return new Date(this.getDataValue('date_of_birth'));
      },
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      validate: {
        isDate: true,
        notEmpty: true,
      },
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'user' },
);
```

Cast `this` type to `User` class will get rid of the error. Don't forget to declare the properties in the `User` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example> It casts the underlying TEXT value in column data to a new JSONB type column called payload:

```
import {DataTypes, Model, Sequelize} from 'sequelize';

export class Book extends Model {
    public id!: number; 
    public name!: string;
    public payload!: any;
    private data!: string;
}

export const initBook = (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
    Book.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
                primaryKey: false
            },
            data: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                primaryKey: false
            },               
            payload: {
                type: DataTypes.JSONB,
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'data',
                get(this: any) {
                    const j = this.getDataValue('payload');
                    return JSON.parse(j);
                }
            }               
        },
        {
            tableName: 'book',
            sequelize // this bit is important
        }
    );
};

export default {Book, initBook};
```